# DispatchQueue vs Delegates vs Closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, grand-central-dispatch

Excuse me if this a noobish question but I don't know the difference between executing a block of code after an API request is received and parsed via GCD, delegates and closures.

As far as I know, a creating a session to download data from an API URL is done on the main thread unless I execute the code inside a a GCD block or a delegate or a closure.

Here are two examples:
Using GCD

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {

        let requestURL = URL(string: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: requestURL!) {
            (data, response, error) in

            print(data as Any)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Hello")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Using Delegate:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol WeatherDataDownloaderProtocol {
    func setData(weatherData: WeatherData)
}

class WeatherDataDownloader {
var weatherData = WeatherData()
var delegate: WeatherDataDownloaderProtocol?

func downloadWeatherData() {
    let API_URL = WEATHER_FORECAST_URL
    guard let URL = URL(string: API_URL) else {
        print("Error: No valid URL")
        return
    }
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error getting data")
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: Did not receive data")
            return
        }

        do {
            guard let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else {
                print("Error: Error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
        }

            print(JSON)

            self.sendDataBack()

        } catch {
            print("Error: Parsing JSON data error")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

    func sendDataBack() {
        if let _delegate = delegate {
            _delegate.setData(weatherData: weatherData)
        }
    }
}
```

Both, print("Hello") and print(JSON) + self.sendDataBack() will execute after the JSON is retrieved and parsed. What's the difference between both methods? Does it have anything to do with whether my app would crash if I navigate out of the viewController while waiting for the network response?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

In your first approach, the `.async` call is not necessary. `URLSession` `dataTask` is a background task.

So the choice is not GDC vs. delegates but completion handler vs. delegate.

Opinion based:

Using a delegate is more work and harder to read because you have to check in other areas of the code if the delegate is actually set and who it is and what it actually does.

Also no code might be executed in case the delegate does not exist any more at the time your network call has finished. So for this case I plead for using a completion closure.

Comment: So why do I see people using GDC with sessions and dataTasks? I have seen it multiple times in other people's code.

Comment: GDC is a framework. You probably see them using a `DispatchQueue`. One reason to do this is to do multible calls _in a defined order_. But this would also not work with your approach. You would have to wait for your `dataTask` to return to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. The block/closure approach is newer and considered to have better readability since you don't have to jump between functions and even between files to follow the course of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {

        let requestURL = URL(string: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: requestURL!) {
            (data, response, error) in

            print(data as Any)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Hello")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

In this method your service hits in background thread and when you completed your in background thread you come back in `main` thread using this method

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Hello")
            }
```

and then your `print("Hello")` will call in main thread.
While the method

> downloadWeatherData

defined in `appdelegate` also hits the service in background thread but in the manner of `closure` because `closure` also works like a background thread. Using `closure` when your task completes your control automatically comes back in main thread where you call `print(JSON)`.

Now comes to your problem, the best thing is that you should wait untill your task complete and you get the json response on your viewcontroller then move to your next controller other your app may crash in some situations.

Comment: I have always known that sessions and dataTasks are performed on the main thread which is why I always have to use closures or GCD.
One of the replies below hints that GCD isn't necessary because the dataTask is performed on a background thread anyways. Which is correct?

Comment: @Tarek you might want to consult Apples Documentation.